# Как создать заголовок из 2 строк в power query?

Tags: excel, powerbi

уважаемые Гении!
Прошу помочь с Power Query.

У меня таблица, на примере файла во вложении, нужно было заголовки собрать из 2 строк. Посмотрел видео по [ссылке](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=voUxyzzPYxM), сделал все так же, но в конце при List.Zip выходит ошибка.

> Expression.Error: Ожидалось значение RenameOperations. Сведения:
> [List]

Вот мой код:

```
let
    Источник = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\Sultanhonov-5680\Desktop\тест.xlsx"), null, true),
    Лист1_Sheet = Источник{[Item="Лист1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Повышенные заголовки" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Лист1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Добавлен пользовательский объект" = Table.AddColumn(#"Повышенные заголовки", "Дата отчета", each 12),
    #"Разделить столбец по положению" = Table.SplitColumn(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Добавлен пользовательский объект", {{"Дата отчета", type text}}, "ru-RU"), "Дата отчета", Splitter.SplitTextByRepeatedLengths(1), {"Дата отчета.1", "Дата отчета.2"}),
    #"Измененный тип1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Разделить столбец по положению",{{"Дата отчета.1", Int64.Type}, {"Дата отчета.2", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Удаленные столбцы" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Измененный тип1",{"Дата отчета.2"}),
    #"Пониженные заголовки" = Table.DemoteHeaders(#"Удаленные столбцы"),
    Пользовательский1 = List.LastN(Record.ToList(#"Пониженные заголовки"{0}),1),
    Пользовательский2 = List.FirstN(Record.ToList(#"Пониженные заголовки"{1}),205),
    Пользовательский3 = Пользовательский2&Пользовательский1,
    Пользовательский4 = Table.DemoteHeaders(#"Удаленные столбцы"),
    #"Удаленные верхние строки" = Table.Skip(Пользовательский4,2),
    Пользовательский5 = Table.RenameColumns(#"Удаленные верхние строки", List.Zip({Table.ColumnNames(#"Удаленные верхние строки"), Пользовательский3}))
in
    Пользовательский5
```

Файл по [ссылке](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/3erh2ma9x95330rmzfhbr/.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=q10fdvo6uyqcdvjdddvmnfr9t)

Comment: Знаешь, Хазратхон, я тоже не понял, почему `List.Zip()` не хочет формировать правильный список пар (возможно, виноват какой-нибудь специальный символ в тексте заголовка, например, в колонке 86 - но это не точно). С другой стороны, преобразование, которое показано в видео, для этой задачи не требуется. Если я правильно понял смысл скрипта, то достаточно трех действий: удалить первую строку (ту, где "19.12.2021 холатига кредит портфели тўгрисида"), использовать первую строку как строку заголовков и добавить колонку "Дата отчета".

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, такой, немного упрощённый подход, решит Вашу проблему:

```
let
    Источник = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\Sultanhonov-5680\Desktop\тест.xlsx"), null, true),
    Лист1_Sheet = Источник{[Item="Лист1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Название Отчета" = Лист1_Sheet{0}[Column2],
    #"Разбить на слова" = Text.Split(#"Название Отчета", " "),
    #"В таблицу" = Table.FromList(#"Разбить на слова", Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Первоначальные заголовки" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Лист1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Окончательные заголовки" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Первоначальные заголовки", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"добавить Дату отчета" = Table.AddColumn(#"Окончательные заголовки", "Дата отчета", each #"В таблицу"{0}[Column1])
in
    #"добавить Дату отчета"
```

Comment: Супер! работает, пусть другим способом, но работает! Как я могу отметить это как решение?